# Launchpad.net : "Lost something?"

Tags: launchpad, apport

I used Apport to report a severe Ubuntu. When sending it, I got told something like:

> The bug you are trying to report has already been reported, please click here to see it and add details to help developers.

I click, and here is what I am told:

[image: Launchpad.net Lost something? This page does not exist, or you may not have permission to see it. If you have been to this page before, it is possible it has been removed. Check that you are logged in with the correct account, or that you entered the address correctly, or search for it]

It is very frustrating. What is happening and why?

- I have further information about this crash that I think is valuable.
- If the crash has been solved, I want to see how.
- Let's say the same crash can be caused in two ways, one benign and one devastating. If the benign way was discovered first, the crash is in limbo somewhere with low priority, this reduces the chances for a fix in the next Ubuntu release.

The problem has happened to me several times:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1671487
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1720694
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1763728
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1765961

Comment: I get the same error for the number shown in your picture.  I'd suggest trying to find it using keywords, package or whatever information you do have.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when the bug report that apport thinks is the "primary" one for that crash is private, probably because it hasn't been reviewed for sensitive user data.  It's probably best to [contact the bug squad](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BugSquad#Contact_us.21) and ask them if they can make that bug public.